# Why am I not able to import other packages in my code?

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, import, package

[Please someone resolve this problem I am facing, what should I do for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k9tc.png)

**bank**

```java
package bank;

class Account {
    public String name;
}

public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

**importingOtherPackages**

```java
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
import bank;

public class ImportingOtherPackages {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bank.Account account1 = new bank.Account(){
            account1.name = "customer1";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should try importing classes, instead of packages

Comment: It looks like the Account class is not public, if you want to use it from outside the package then make it accessible.

Comment: The reason is right there in the error message: `Account` is not public, so it can only be used inside the package `bank`. And `import bank` is invalid, because you cannot import a package, only classes.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using `import bank.Bank;` instead of `import bank;` as Bank is the class.